# How to replace all values of rows into NA?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to replace all values of rows (in range) into NA. How can I do it?

For example:

```
x <- c(1:30)
y <- c("a","b","c")
z <- rep(3)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I need to replace all values of the rows (1:10) into NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use row index for assignment

```
df1[1:10, ] <- NA
```

-output

```
df1
    x    y  z
1  NA <NA> NA
2  NA <NA> NA
3  NA <NA> NA
4  NA <NA> NA
5  NA <NA> NA
6  NA <NA> NA
7  NA <NA> NA
8  NA <NA> NA
9  NA <NA> NA
10 NA <NA> NA
11 11    b  3
12 12    c  3
13 13    a  3
14 14    b  3
15 15    c  3
16 16    a  3
17 17    b  3
18 18    c  3
19 19    a  3
20 20    b  3
21 21    c  3
22 22    a  3
23 23    b  3
24 24    c  3
25 25    a  3
26 26    b  3
27 27    c  3
28 28    a  3
29 29    b  3
30 30    c  3
```